# ARC - Deallocating Image Gallery Picker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm building an app for the iPad and am a little confused as to why ARC is deallocating a strong property declared like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *imagePickerPopover;
```

I'm using this UIPopoverController to display the users Image Gallery since you have to do it this way if your building for iPad. Anyone experience this? It only gives me this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'
```

randomly when I'm opening it. (for example I might be able to open up the gallery without the exception once but not twice or three times but the fourth it throws the exception) It's really quite bizarre.

Here is my code for creating the picker:

```
self.imagePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[self.imagePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:aUIButton.frame inView:aUIButton.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: We need to see how you are creating your UIPopoverController.

Comment: Are you running that code every time the user taps a control? You should check of the popover controller already exists, and then only create a new one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that I was actually trying to make that picker pop up more then once while it was opened. SO I just used the isPopoverVisible property to check and if it wasn't then I created and displayed the popover. Problem fixed.